# JAVA Button Alignment

Tags: java, swing, button, jframe

First, this is homework, I'm not looking for the complete answer but I am hoping to get an idea of how to do what is needed. I am trying to align buttons in a JFrame to appear as such: 
What GUI should look like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOSsB.jpg]

However, being new to GUI making as of this week I'm having difficulty. I was attempting to utilize FlowLayout but eventually, I came to the conclusion that it is not the proper way to achieve the desired results. This is what I have:

Current build:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y51ke.png]

I have now way to add the text box underneath and I think I need to use grid layout. The catch being that I've never used grid layout (or FlowLayout for that matter!).

If I understand grid layout, I was thinking a 5x8 would work. It would allow for spacing horizontally and vertically. Am I on the right track with this line of thought? Or is it possible to continue with what I am currently doing?

Code is attached for those that wish to see what I'm working with.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ATM extends JFrame {

    //create objects to add to JPanel
    private JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Checking");
    private JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("Savings");
    private JButton withdrawBtn = new JButton("Withdraw");
    private JButton depositBtn = new JButton("Deposit");
    private JButton transferBtn = new JButton("Transfer");
    private JButton balanceBtn = new JButton("Balance");

    public ATM() {
        super("ATM");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());  

        //add buttons to JPanel
        JPanel buttonsPanel1 = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        buttonsPanel1.add(withdrawBtn);
        buttonsPanel1.add(balanceBtn);
        add(buttonsPanel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel buttonsPanel2 = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel2.add(transferBtn);
        buttonsPanel2.add(depositBtn);
        add(buttonsPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel buttonsPanel3 = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel3.add(radio1);
        buttonsPanel3.add(radio2);
        add(buttonsPanel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

         /**
        *
        * @param args
  */}
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ATM app = new ATM();
        app.setSize(400,300);
        app.setVisible(true);
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into `GridBagLayout` or even `SpringLayout`. And if you've not seen it yet, [this is very helpful](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) Also a couple of semantics: BorderLayout.NORTH is considered ['old fashioned'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) and the comment just above 'main' is a touch bizarre.

Comment: First and foremost, get rid of `app.setSize(400,300);` or any `setSize(...)` or `setPreferredSize(...)`. Use your layout managers, call `pack()` on your JFrame after adding all components, and then set it visible.

Comment: BTW - *"ATM Machine"*. Given ATM stands for Automatic Teller Machine, that actually means *"Automatic Teller **Machine Machine**"*.

Comment: @Overt_Agent, thank you for the link. One would think that something like that would have been included in this week's material, but no.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, app.setSize no longer exists. Thank you for introducing pack() it is now present

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, thanks for the catch. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You have a nice code to start with. Infact using BorderLayout, you can accomplish the task.

Please note that you can call the layout manager on any Swing container. For example the code below is okay to help you get the work done.

```
JPanel buttonsPanel3 = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
buttonsPanel3.add(radio1, BorderLayout.WEST);
buttonsPanel3.add(radio2, BorderLayout.EAST);
buttonsPanel3.add(txtAmount, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

However, your code should look like this :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ATM extends JFrame {

//create objects to add to JPanel
private JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Checking");
private JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("Savings");
private JButton withdrawBtn = new JButton("Withdraw");
private JButton depositBtn = new JButton("Deposit");
private JButton transferBtn = new JButton("Transfer");
private JButton balanceBtn = new JButton("Balance");
private JTextField txtAmount = new JTextField();
public ATM() {
    super("ATM");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());  

//add buttons to JPanel
JPanel buttonsPanel1 = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
buttonsPanel1.add(withdrawBtn);
buttonsPanel1.add(balanceBtn);
add(buttonsPanel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
JPanel buttonsPanel2 = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel2.add(transferBtn);
buttonsPanel2.add(depositBtn);
add(buttonsPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JPanel buttonsPanel3 = new JPanel();
buttonsPanel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
buttonsPanel3.add(radio1, BorderLayout.WEST);
buttonsPanel3.add(radio2, BorderLayout.EAST);
buttonsPanel3.add(txtAmount, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(buttonsPanel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
// This method will set adjust the size of the container so it can contain all other controls
pack();
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
ATM app = new ATM();
//app.setSize(400,300);// This line is not very helpful in this situation instead avoid it
app.setVisible(true);
app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
app.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }
}
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and the example on how to properly do everything. Yourself and others pointed out "pack();" which is something I was unaware of. I have continued working on the code and am now in the process of adding actions to all buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This layout can be achieved with a single 2 column grid layout (for the buttons and check boxes) and a border layout (to contain the button/check box panel and text field). Put the panel with buttons and check boxes in the `PAGE_START` of the border layout. Put the text field in the `PAGE_END`.

Use appropriate empty borders on both panels to create the white space.

Comment: Hi Andrew! Thank you for the quick reply. I have been messing around with grid layout since my initial post but will likely stay with the current format I have for this scenario as GUIs are new to me (as of this week) and the grid layout hasn't quite sunk in yet. I do appreciate the time you took though and will continue experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

To create a UI like in the example, I would use a `GridLayout`. To ensure that GridLayout uses 2 columns you must set it to 0 rows either with the `setRows` method or with the constructor. I have created an example for you where the output looks like so:

[image: output from ATM UI]

These are two separate files

ATM.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ATM extends JFrame {

    public ATM() {
        super("ATM");
        setSize(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        add(new ATMPanel());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ATM app = new ATM();
    }
}
```

ATMPanel.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ATMPanel extends JPanel {

    private class Buttons extends JPanel {
        //create objects to add to JPanel
        private JButton withdrawBtn;
        private JButton balanceBtn;
        private JButton depositBtn;
        private JButton transferBtn;
        private JRadioButton radio1;
        private JRadioButton radio2;

        private Buttons() {
            //initialize buttons
            this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
            this.withdrawBtn = new JButton("Withdraw");
            this.balanceBtn = new JButton("Balance");
            this.depositBtn = new JButton("Deposit");
            this.transferBtn = new JButton("Transfer");
            this.radio1 = new JRadioButton("Checking");
            this.radio2 = new JRadioButton("Savings");

            //add buttons
            this.add(withdrawBtn);
            this.add(balanceBtn);
            this.add(depositBtn);
            this.add(transferBtn);
            this.add(radio1);
            this.add(radio2);
        }
    }

    public ATMPanel() {
        add(new Buttons());


    }
}
```

I have divided the panel holding the button into its own class. The reason for doing so is that you can have multiple panels on a frame, and they can all have different layouts. You have this panel with a `GridLayout` which will make the buttons it has line up nicely, but then you can move that panel around at a higher level with a different type of layout manager.

I understand this problem is merely dealing with UI but when you decide to make these buttons actually *do* something I would suggest doing handling in a button class and then actions inside an engine/model class.

Comment: Michael, thank you for the response. I am very interested in separating classes in this format. To date, I have little experience with it simply do to where I am in learning JAVA. However, I know it is something I have to learn, especially since I am in the process of making the buttons do something like you surmised.

Comment: *"I am very interested in separating classes in this format."* For the record, there is no need to extend either `JFrame` or `JPanel` in this case.